# How do you configure firewall to map ports outside to a device inside lan?

Tags: firewall

Using TPLink omada sdn controller, I wanna map remote desktop connection 3389 on my home computer (uses a fixed IP address) to port 4000 on the WAN interface...

Cant seem to figure out how to do this

Comment: Is there a port forwarding option anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping addresses & ports is called "NAT", and mapping *destination* addresses & ports is called "DNAT" (destination NAT) which is also known as "port forwarding".

I searched for "omaha sdn dnat" and it brought me to [section 4.6.2 NAT](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/omada-sdn-software-controller/chapter-4-configure-the-network-with-omada-sdn-controller.html#_idTextAnchor030) of the user guide.

> ##### Configuration
>
> ■ Port Forwarding
>
> 1. Go to **Setting > Transmission > NAT > Port Forwarding** . Click + Create New Rule to load the following page and configure the parameters.
>
> [image]

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to look at NAT.  Thanks!